# How to concatenate a multiple dimensional array into a formatted string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Given an Excel array/table/pivot table with 2 columns and x rows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 10 |
| Item2 | 20 |
| ... | ... |
| Itemx | 9999 |

Is there an array formula that allows to create the following text string result (potentially using a combination of concatenate and textjoin, or something like scan that allows running a lambda for items in an array?)

> Item1 (10), Item2 (20), ... (...) , Itemx (9999)

I do know its possible to add another column that concatenates the values and then textjoin that column, but I'm looking for a solution that does it all within a formula because I believe Excel can do it and it's a more convenient solution.

Answer (score 3):

[image: screenshot]

It seems quite straight-forward with a simple `TEXTJOIN` formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,A1:A5&" ("&B1:B5&")")
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9htYqXWpLA2HIe97u6Q?e=G8QqC9) (excel template)/below refer.

*(no lambdas required)...*

```
=LET(x_,B2:C6,y_,TEXTJOIN("",1,IF(--ISNUMBER(x_),"("&x_&"), ",x_)),MID(y_,1,LEN(y_)-2))
```

[image: Sample illustration]

Comment: minor comment, I guess the parenthesis should be included in the output.

Comment: heh?  not sure I follow mate.  kindly expand  - ahhh yes sure fair point - can update accordingly no hassle (hopefully)!

Comment: Spot on Mr @DavidLeal - I didn't even notice that tbh :) luckily found a fairly rough n ready workaround/hack lol :) keep it real mate. go well - thanks again, shot

Answer (score 0):

You may try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,
BYROW(A1:B4,LAMBDA(x,
CHOOSECOLS(x,1)&"("&CHOOSECOLS(x,2)&")"))
)
```

[image]